# ShowHelp in dual-monitor

Tags: wpf, helper, multiple-monitors

I wonder how I can open help on the second monitor.
I'm using Help.ShowHelp(null, path, TopicId, index)
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the ShowHelp-Methode to show up on a second screen. If you need more control over there to show the help you have to implement it by yourself. The only possible solution I can think of would be to get the help window via its process id and reposition it with the user32.dll, but it's not a very neat solution.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int flags);
```

Comment: And how can i do it?
How can i get the help window via its process id and reposition it with the user32.dll?

Comment: @Vitor With the help of Google - [ask]